# Replacing widget with custom template widget in Qt Creator Designer

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

In Qt Creator UI Designer it is possible to replace a widget with its subclass. I have created a template subclass of `QComboBox`:

```
template <typename T>
class MappedComboBox : public QComboBox
{
    // ...
};
```

And I have successfully managed to replace `QComboBox` with `MappedComboBox<int>`. However replacing `QComboBox` widget with, for instance, `MappedComboBox<QSerialPort::BaudRate>` fails due to dependency errors while building like

> 'QSerialPort' was not declared in this scope.

[image: Qt Designer screenshot]

Of course one way to get rid of them is to include `QSerialPort` in `mappedcombobox.h` however that's not a very elegant way. Can I somehow tell Qt Designer to include additional files while generating UI?

Comment: Try in Qt Designer in the promote dialog check the "global" check box. And in the header line edit write qserialport.h.

Comment: @Radek Good idea, but doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Qt moc doesn't support template classes with all running out problems. Try to inherit your widget for exact types: `MappedIntComboBox : public MappedComboBox< int >`;

Comment: @SaZ Hey, I realize that QT MOC doesn't support template classes with signals and slots, but it's not a problem here. Everything works fine except that it doesn't include the needed files in `ui_mainwindow.h` and I need to do quite ugly workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In the UI designer there is no way to include an extra header. A better workaround is to include it in the cpp file of the designer class before including the generated header. That's better than including in the MappedComboBox which has no business with that header.

In mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QSerialPort>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
```